# Is tracking modified fields in hibernate envers still an experimental feature?

Tags: hibernate-envers

i want to use this feature, configuration is:

```
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag"alue="true"/>
```

is this still an experimental feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's been there long enough to be considered stable. You can file a [JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa) to fix the documentation :)

Comment: A JIRA has been added https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11460 for this to be addressed in ORM 6.0.